# Detectando change de ion-textarea com ionic2

Tags: typescript, ionic2

Estou desenvolvendo um app e eu precisava detectar o ionChange ou keyUp de um ion-textarea no ionic 2.

Segue abaixo exemplos que funcionam.

> meu-arquivo.ts

```
atualizar() {
 console.log('Atualizou :)');
}
```

> meu .html

```
<!-- FUNCIONA -->
<ion-checkbox (ionChange)="atualizar()"></ion-checkbox>
<!-- Não funciona -->
<ion-textarea (ionChange)="atualizar()"></ion-textarea>
```

Olhei na documentação oficial e não achei nada podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Consegui pessoal, usei a diretiva do próprio angular2.

Segue abaixo exemplo

```
<ion-textarea (keyup)="atualizar()">
```

Fonte: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/user-input.html#!#sts=Key%20event%20filtering%20(with%20key.enter)

Comment: Thank you, your response help me!

Comment: Glad you helped him ;)